# Missing SQL tab when using AD provider

Tags: opserver

I've deployed a copy of opserver, and it is working perfectly when using `alladmin` as the security setting. However, once I switch it to `ad` and configure the groups, the SQL tab goes away and I get an access denied message if I try browsing directly to it. The dashboard still displays all Solar Winds data as expected.

The build I'm using is actually from November. I tried a more recent build, but I lose the network information from Solar Winds (the CPU and Mem graphs show, but Net is all blank)

Is there a separate place to configure the SQL permissions that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps there was some caching going on for the hub that wasn't happening for the provider, because they are both working now. Since it was a new security group, perhaps it hadn't replicated yet (causing the SQL auth to fail) but the dashboard provider was still using the previous authentication?

I also did discover a neat option while researching this though - the GitHub page mentions that you can also specify security at a provider level in the JSON using the AdminGroups and ViewGroups properties!